# Edit View Cart Page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart

I'm trying to edit the View Cart Page, my theme has ab image block on the page that I'm trying to edit but I can't figure out which file I need to edit.

more information

when something is added to the cart, and you click to view it before paying there is a block that has discount codes and grand total. in my theme to there is a promo image that I'm trying to change but I'm not sure which file to change. I checked it in firebug and the section lights up seems to be called

Comment: Can You Provide More infromation @New2Magento

Comment: sorry when something is added to the cart, and you click to view it before paying there is a block that has discount codes and grand total. in my theme to there is a promo image that I'm trying to change but I'm not sure which file to change. I checked it in firebug and the section lights up seems to be called <body class=" checkout-cart-index">

Answer (score 1):

You give us little informations but if want the path of checkout cart page, you follow this one:

```
app/design/frontend/{namePackageHere}/{ThemeNameHere}/template/checkout/cart.phtml
```

**Nb:**

> It is possible that a block is displayed in this page cart page but when you go
>   in this page you don't find explicitly the information that you need, that said the
>   this information can be stored as block often declared in **xml** ! I don't
>   know exactly What you are looking for but check also in the layout `local.xml` and the `xml extension` if you have.

Comment: sorry when something is added to the cart, and you click to view it before paying there is a block that has discount codes and grand total. in my theme to there is a promo image that I'm trying to change but I'm not sure which file to change. I checked it in firebug and the section lights up seems to be called <body class=" checkout-cart-index">

Comment: no checkout-cart-index is couter class of the page, try to check in the files after `app/design/frontend/{namePackageHere}/{ThemeNameHere}/template/checkout/cart/...`  totals.phtml , coupon.phtml, ... i can't give you an exact file with the few informations that you provided

Comment: here is a screen shot of the section http://imgur.com/a/6irnZ

Comment: I see, this image is not in natif magento block, please look this tuto `http://support.magerewards.com/article/1534-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints` to find the path hint of your image block.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the exact block that is being used by turning on template path hints

Go to SYSTEM - CONFIGURATION then change the Current Configuration Scope to be Website or View (anything lower level than Default Config will work) and then go to the ADVANCED - Developer tab and choose DEBUG - here turn on Template Path Hints setting to yes (also Add Block Names to Hints if you want that info). Flush cache if cache is enabled and visit the checkout page.

You will be able to see the exact file you need to edit and path details.